# Cordova 2.7.0 PushPlugin "cordova cannot be resolved" and "ctx cannot be resolved"

Tags: android, apache, cordova, phonegap-plugins

What I've done....

- Created the cordova project using ./create in the cordova-android bin
- Added PushPlugin via [cordova-plugman](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugman)
- Added cordova-2.7.0.jar to the /libs directory

Cordova is complaining in PushPlugin.java that "cordova cannot be resolved" ...along with several other errors...

```
(PushPlugin.java) Plugin cannot be resolved to a type
(PushPlugin.java) Plugin cannot be resolved to a type
(PushPlugin.java) cordova cannot be resolved
(PushPlugin.java) Plugin cannot be resolved to a type
(PushPlugin.java) Plugin cannot be resolved to a type
(PushPlugin.java) ctx cannot be resolved or is not a field
(PushPlugin.java) ctx cannot be resolved
(PushPlugin.java) ctx cannot be resolved
(PushPlugin.java) ctx cannot be resolved or is not a field
(PushPlugin.java) Plugin cannot be resolved to a type
(PushPlugin.java) The method execute(String, JSONArray, String) of type PushPlugin must override or implement a supertype method
```

[image]

I've added the cordova-2.7.0 project to the class path via Project >> Properties >> JAVA Build Path >> Add Jar Files

I've also ran... Project >> clean

Can't seem to figure this one out... it's been several days and many google searches.

Best Regards, John
[image: errors]

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670010/getting-error-in-childbrowser-java

Comment: HI obitusis, Have You got the solution as I am getting same error?

Comment: i think you have to upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the latest commit at: [NetMatch:PushPlugin github](https://github.com/NetMatch/PushPlugin/tree/30a413b8c90207396cfaee1949032baa2615ebae)

Looks like the man did a great job at cleaning up the plugin for recent cordova releases. Still awaiting the PushPlugin repo to accept the pull request.

Comment: Just finished pulling from NetMatch:PushPlugin repo into my own PushPlugin repo and it worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

I'm troubleshooting a similar problem with the [ChildBrowser plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/ChildBrowser) in Cordova 2.7.0. Changing **extends Plugin** to **extends CordovaPlugin** in the plugin class declaration got rid of the "cordova cannot be resolved" errors on my end. See if the following change works for you:

```
public class PushPlugin extends Plugin {
```

to:

```
public class PushPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
```

Comment: See the answer here for the rest of the changes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755336/phonegap-2-3-0-and-the-foregroundcamera-plugin

Comment: The method 'execute' excepted JSONArray args... adding "data = args;" solved the data variable problem.

Comment: Here's my attempt at updating ChildBrowser (I am not a Java developer): https://github.com/robdiciuccio/ChildBrowser/commit/a621ab8c6d8837744f6d47de67c4473893da881c